# Click event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a visual web-part for sharepoint with code below, but code of click-handler is never firing. What's wrong with my code?:

```
protected Button btApply;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ... some code ...
    btApply = new Button();
    btApply.Text = "Apply";
    btApply.CssClass += "InputControl";
    btApply.Click += new EventHandler(btApplyClick);
    this.Controls.Add(btApply);
    ... some code ...
}

protected void btApplyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ... some code ...
}
```

Comment: the initialization of control must be in preinit event so that the page life cycle can take advante of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to create controls dynamically, you have to to it in `Page_PreInit`. A quote from `MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-515): Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4`, page 106:

> You can add controls to a form at run time by handling the
>   Page.PreInit event (if you are not using master pages) or the
>   Page.Init event (if you are using master pages and you are adding the
>   control to a content page)

The page (as well as web-part, user control, etc.) lifecycle is explained in MSDN "[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)" article.

Also, see the quite similar question [Event for Dynamically created Controls in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485800/event-for-dynamically-created-controls-in-asp-net)

So, just move your control creation and event wiring-up into `Page_PreInit` and you should be fine.